# find ranges to create Uniform histogram

Tags: sql, r, statistics

I need to find ranges in order to create a Uniform histogram

i.e: ages
to 4 ranges

```
data_set = [18,21,22,24,27,27,28,29,30,32,33,33,42,42,45,46]
```

is there a function that gives me the ranges so the histogram is uniform?

in this case

```
ranges = [(18,24), (27,29), (30,33), (42,46)]
```

This example is easy, I'd like to know if there is an algorithm that deals with complex data sets as well

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the quantiles that split up your data equally. This combined with `cut`should work. So, suppose you want `n` groups.

```
set.seed(1)  
x <- rnorm(1000)  # Generate some toy data
n <- 10
uniform <- cut(x, c(-Inf, quantile(x, prob = (1:(n-1))/n), Inf)) # Determine the groups
plot(uniform)
```

[image: Imgur]

Edit: now corrected to yield the correct cuts in the ends.

Edit2: I don't quite understand the downvote. But this also works in your example:

```
data_set = c(18,21,22,24,27,27,28,29,30,32,33,33,42,42,45,46)
n <- 4
groups <- cut(data_set, breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(data_set, prob = 1:(n-1)/n), Inf))
levels(groups)
```

With some minor renaming nessesary. For slightly better level names, you could also put in `min(x)` and `max(x)` instead of `-Inf` and `Inf`.